# unhashable type: 'list' in bag of words

Tags: python, list, dataframe, hash, tuples

I have two list of words and I want a union of them. I tried the following method below but unsuccessful so far.

```
bowA = df["Lang_1_text"].str.split(" ") 
bowB = df["Lang_2_text"].str.split(" ")
```

```
print(bowA)
>>>[strike, kirsten, chlodowski, file, exchange]
print(bowB)
>>> [kirsten, exchange, outlook, freeze ]
```

**Expected result:**

```
wordSet = set(bowA).union(set(bowB))

print(wordSet)
>>>[strike, kirsten, chlodowski, file, exchange, outlook, freeze]
```

**Actual result:**

TypeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
    in 
    wordSet = set(bowA).union(set(bowB)) 
    TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Please show the actual code to reproduce the error, as well as the error itself with the traceback pointing to where in your code it originates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when you do:

```
bowA = df["Lang_1_text"].str.split(" ") 
bowB = df["Lang_2_text"].str.split(" ")
```

bowA and bowB will be a Series object.
You can verify by printing them. It will be like below:

```
>> type(bowA)
>> pandas.core.series.Series
>> type(bowA[0])
>> list
```

And each element in the Series will be a list. When you cast it to set(), it raises the TypeError.
Example:

```
>> set([1,2,3]) # runs fine
>> set([[1],2,3]) # will raise the same error - TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

You should probably do something like below:

```
>> data = {"Lang_1_text": ['strike kirsten chlodowski file exchange'], "Lang_2_text": ['kirsten exchange outlook freeze']} 
>> df = pd.DataFrame(data) # Assuming `df` is the format you have 
>> # Now split it on space " "; and cast them as `set()` you can user `applymap`
>> # https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html
>> data_1 = df.applymap(lambda x: set(x.split(" ")))
>> # Calculate the `union` data
>> union_data = data_1.apply(lambda x: x['Lang_1_text'].union(x['Lang_2_text']), axis=1)
>> print union_data.values[0]  # Or list(union_data.values[0]) to make it a list
>> {'chlodowski', 'exchange', 'file', 'freeze', 'kirsten', 'outlook', 'strike'}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Something doesn't add up. This code works for me:

```
bowA = ['strike', 'kirsten', 'chlodowski', 'file', 'exchange']
bowB = ['kirsten', 'exchange', 'outlook', 'freeze']

wordSet = set(bowA).union(set(bowB))
print(wordSet)
```

Although you can usually fix unhashable type errors by tuple-casting lists, there's some sort of disconnect because hashability shouldn't matter here.